# JDBC Netbeans java+mysql project Connection statement show error, `Erroneous sym type: java.lang.Object.getConnection`

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, compiler-errors

I have tried to insert data into MySQL database using java language, I have used Netbeans as a development IDE. But I get a few errors in my code. I also add JDBC driver in project library but show the `getConnection` error in code.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.lang.Object.getConnection

java code:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.*; 

package project1;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
private Object DriverManager;

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Rollno = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    fname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    lname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    address = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("RollNo");

    jLabel2.setText("First Name");

    jLabel3.setText("Last Name");

    jLabel4.setText("Address");

    jButton1.setText("Insert");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Update");

    jButton3.setText("Delete");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setText("New");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton4))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(Rollno, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 107, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(fname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(address))))
            .addContainerGap(433, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(Rollno, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(fname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(lname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(address, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addComponent(jButton4))
            .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO persons(fname, lname, address) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test3","root","");

        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,fname.getText());
        pst.setString(2,lname.getText());
        pst.setString(3,address.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert Successfull");
    } catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        String sql = "Delete from test3 where Rollno=?";
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test3","root",""); 
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,Rollno.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delete Successfull");
    } catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField Rollno;
private javax.swing.JTextField address;
private javax.swing.JTextField fname;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField lname;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Can you help me solve these errors in my code?

Comment: Please also post here your import statements.

Comment: Showed this error after click submit button.                                                                                                        `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
 at NewJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:146)
 at NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:8)
 at NewJFrame$1.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:50)`

Comment: I've requsted your import statements. Not a stack trace.

Comment: `import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;`

Comment: Add `import javax.swing.*;`

Comment: Thank you, sir. `JOptionPane` error is solved. but show the `getConnection` error.

Comment: now run code show the `Erroneous sym type: java.lang.Object.getConnection` error.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson ok sir, I post pictures for describe my erros.

Comment: Please edit your topic and post the complete code of your class, icluding all import statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to remove the line: `private Object DriverManager;`

```
package project1;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Rollno = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        fname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        lname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        address = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("RollNo");

        jLabel2.setText("First Name");

        jLabel3.setText("Last Name");

        jLabel4.setText("Address");

        jButton1.setText("Insert");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Update");

        jButton3.setText("Delete");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("New");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jButton4))
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                                .addComponent(Rollno, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 107, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(fname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addComponent(lname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addComponent(address))))
                        .addContainerGap(433, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addComponent(Rollno, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addComponent(fname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addComponent(lname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addComponent(address, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jButton1)
                                .addComponent(jButton2)
                                .addComponent(jButton3)
                                .addComponent(jButton4))
                        .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            String sql = "INSERT INTO persons(fname, lname, address) VALUES (?,?,?)";

            //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test3","root","");

            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,fname.getText());
            pst.setString(2,lname.getText());
            pst.setString(3,address.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert Successfull");
        } catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            String sql = "Delete from test3 where Rollno=?";
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test3","root",""); 
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,Rollno.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delete Successfull");
        } catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField Rollno;
    private javax.swing.JTextField address;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fname;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField lname;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```